# Quasar and webpack devServer ECONNREFUSED on docker compose

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server, quasar

I am trying to develop an app through `docker-compose`. This app has three components: a frontend (built with the Quasar framework) and a backend (built with python/flask), and another API (not relevant here). The problem is: when I execute `docker-compose up` in my project's directory, the frontend runs perfectly (I'm able to access it via browser), but when I make a request to the backend (by clicking on a certain button in the front) I'm met with the following error in the terminal:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/projects from
> 0.0.0.0:8080 to https://backend:5000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

And I receive a `504` status code.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: "./backend"
    volumes:
      - "./backend/venv"
      - "./backend:/usr/app"
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=dev
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: "./frontend"
    volumes:
      - "./frontend/node_modules"
      - "./frontend:/usr/app"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: "./api"
    volumes:
      - "./api:/usr/app"
    expose:
      - "3000"
```

Here is the `devServer` object inside my `quasar.conf.js` file:

```
    devServer: {
      https: true,
      // open: true, // opens browser window automatically
      proxy: {
        "/api": {
          target: source,
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: false,
          secure: false,
        },
        "/login": {
          target: source,
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: false,
          secure: false,
        },
        "/logout": {
          target: source,
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: false,
          secure: false,
        },
        "/media": {
          target: source,
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: false,
          secure: false,
        },
      },
    },
```

Futhermore, `source` is defined as `const source = "https://backend:5000"`

So, why am I getting this error and how should I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quasar embeds the webpack DevServer, and this by default only listens on the `localhost` interface.  In a Docker context, though, each container has its own `localhost`, and if something listens only to `localhost` then it won't be reachable from outside its own container.

In your Quasar configuration, you need to change the [`host`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost) property to be the special 0.0.0.0 "everywhere" address:

```js
devServer: {
  host: '0.0.0.0', // <-- add this
  https: true,
  ...
}
```

If you make this change in your Dockerfile, perhaps by `COPY`ing a production-oriented configuration file in place of the normal configuration, don't forget to delete the `volumes:` blocks in the `docker-compose.yml` that hide all of the Dockerfiles' work.

Comment: strange - for me it works also without `host: '0.0.0.0'`